# Test nodejs server code without running server

Tags: node.js, unit-testing

New to nodejs testing.

I have a nodejs server that runs some complex server side logic, and I'm looking at building a unit test runner for that code. I do ***not*** want to run the server and tests sending it requests though, as that doesn't expose all the modules and functions I want to test on the server side. That will be more like integration testing. I just want to import those server side files, which are written as AMD modules, and call their functions one by one in unit tests.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to start by installing a unit-test and assertion framework to your current project. Then you will also want to add [requirejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs) (r.js).

We are currently using [mochajs](https://mochajs.org/) for unit-testing with [should](https://www.npmjs.com/package/should) as the assertion library. Both have great adoption and feature support for testing Node.js.

```
npm install mochajs shouldjs requirejs --save-dev
```

This will add three packages to your local node_modules as well as save them inside your package.json's devDependencies.

Go ahead and setup a unit test directory in your project and create a new test file, [your_module_name]_test.js:

```
const should = require('should'),
      foo = require('foo');

describe('foo', () => {
  it('returns the letter a', () => {
    foo().should.eql('a');
  });
});
```

In the test file you will want to require the module under test and then unit-test as usual.

You can then run the test through r.js

```
./node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js [your_test_dir]/[your_module_name]_test.js
```

You can also install mochajs globally and then simply run the mocha command instead of using the bin inside of your local node_modules.

Best of luck, and hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm actually using mochajs too, but I'm having issues trying to require an AMD module in the test script, or in a node repl. Does `require('path/to/amd/module')` work for you in node?

Comment: Not currently using any AMD style modules, have you taken a look at possibly running it through r.js? https://github.com/requirejs/r.js

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks! If you edit the answer to add this bit I'll accept it, since it was part of the original question. :)